# How can I get pm2 to use my ecosystem.config.js file on reboot?

Tags: pm2

My ecosystem.config.js file loads my environment great with this command:

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

When I run any of these command, my environment is reloaded just fine:

```
pm2 reload myapp
pm2 restart myapp
pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js
pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js
```

Then I try to make sure I get my environment back after a reboot.  If I run `pm2 startup` I get this:

`sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u me --hp /home/me`

After running that command, I can reboot my machine and my application is restarted automatically.  However, I am missing my environment from the `ecosystem.config.js` file.  Why?  How do I make sure the environment from my `ecosystem.config.js` environment is loaded when the machine is rebooted?  Thanks.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779272/6908282) talks about how to make pm2 to use `ecosystem.config.js`

Answer (score 26):

Dont forget to save your config! **pm2 save**

In case you want pm2 on startup with changed logs path:

```
pm2 delete all
pm2 start ecosystem.js
pm2 save
pm2 startup
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. After executing the command suggested by `pm2 startup`, I found I had to first run `pm2 delete all`, then restart using `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`. My environment is now loading as expected after rebooting.

Answer (score 4):

May be worth sharing that a file named `ecosystem.js`, even if empty, needs to exist on the system in the user's home path so that pm2 can load it.