# 500 error when I try to deploy nextjs ssg application with incremental-static-generation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, next.js

I have NextJS app with SSG. This functionality was added recently and according to it I should do `next-export` after `next-build` to get static files. But after appearing in 9.4 of Incremental Static Regeneration I need to keep server on by `npm-start` command (in my case I use custom server file with next-express functionality). It works good locally and It works good when I get artifact from Azure. But It doesn't work globally when it will be deployed finally. Help please

Comment: In order to help people trying to answer the question, Please attach any deployment/access logs that provide a meaningful error or stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Through my attempts, I found that it is impossible to install globally or use `next` in Azure Web App. That is, it cannot be deployed through Github.Deploying using other methods such as FTP cannot run successfully. It should be related to the azure node environment.

[But the method provided in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908662/unable-to-deploy-next-js-to-azure) says that it can be processed by adding `web.config`. I think it should be useful and helpful to you. Please read it carefully and try it.

You also can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs), maybe it useful to you.

Comment: yeah, I have web.config, it worked while I used SSR. but when I moved to SSG and start it through `node server.js ..` - it stopped

Comment: @RomanRemniov Sorry, what is the full name of ssg? I always thought ssg was the content of nextjs.

Comment: SSG - static site generation, earlier It worked only with `next-export` but couple months ago Next added feature Incremental Static Regeneration which works with usual server after `next-start`. It works on vercel but It doesn't on Azure

Comment: @RomanRemniov https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure/deploy-next-js-with-azure-static-web-app-service-and-github/m-p/1413932

Comment: thanks, but this way through next export (outdated way)