# NextJs router seems very slow compare to React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a website built in React Js and the same one on Next Js as well.

The problem which I am facing right now is, the router seems very slow in the nextJs compare to react-router-dom, It's taking almost 2-3 seconds to change the route.

Here are the URLs where you can feel the difference between the performance by moving around different pages.

https://cutt.ly/mhbPkOE (React Router Dom) vs
https://cutt.ly/BhbPvHv (NextJs)

I had read some comments on Github where few experts are saying that It will resolve in production. but It looks same in production too.

Please have a look at the following code

**_app.jsx**

```
// import App from 'next/app'
import React from "react"
import Router from 'next/router';

import "../static/sass/application.scss";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { wrapper } from "../../redux/utils/store"

import App from 'next/app';
// A simple component that we created
import {LoaderOverlay} from '../components/Reusable'
class MyApp extends App {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        }
        Router.onRouteChangeStart = (url) => {
            // Some page has started loading
            this.setState({
                isLoading: true,
            }) // set state to pass to loader prop
        };
    
        Router.onRouteChangeComplete = (url) => {
            // Some page has finished loading
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
            }) // set state to pass to loader prop
        };
    
        Router.onRouteChangeError = (err, url) => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false,})
        }; 
    };
    render() {
        const {Component, pageProps} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoading ? (
                    <LoaderOverlay/>
                ) : (
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

**_document.jsx**

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

        ctx.renderPage = () =>
            originalRenderPage({
            // useful for wrapping the whole react tree
            enhanceApp: (App) => App,
            // useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
            enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
            })

        // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

        return initialProps
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                <link async rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.1/dist/semantic.min.css"/>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <div className={'main-wrapper'}>
                        <Main />
                    </div>
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: well that is because in next.js the pages are server-rendered while on SPA react it isn't you can render your pages as static pages on next.js depends on your needs everything has its pros and cons maybe it is better to build your app as React SPA if you don't need SEO optimization.

Comment: well, I already have this app in React JS, but obviously I need SEO optimized as well that's why I choose Next Js to make my app SEO friendly. I was hoping It won't affect performance at least in the router.

Comment: Same problem in 2023. I have a very minimalistic app, some routes don't need any new data from the server (all the data is already on the page, I just have cards that when clicked are opened in a modal and show the data in a bit different format). I'm using shadow routing (when the actual URL that the browser sees is different from what the router sees). I have the `shallow` prop on all the `Link`s.

Somehow, still, in production, my cards are taking anywhere from 300ms to 2s to open in a modal.

If I use React useState to track the opened card instead of the router, the opening takes 50ms

Answer (score 11):

Development mode (`next dev`) is much slower because the routes aren't pre-built.

All delay related to routing assuming you don't have any server side blocking data requirements via getInitialProps, getServerSideProps, should not be present when running production mode with `next build` followed by `next start`.

Comment: This is helpful. I initially had a `server.js` file created to serve my app in Azure (_which meant I cannot use `next start`_) and it was very slow (**around 11s**). But based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779272/6908282), I used `PM2` to serve my application from Azure App service and now the app in production is quick (**around 250ms**)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found a fix for this yet, but I came across this article about "shallow routing". I can't see much improvement in my application when using it, but maybe it will help someone else:

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to access your cutt.ly examples, but I've encountered a similar issue when using router.push(/dashboard/some_path). The issue arises because every time you use router.push, it triggers getInitialProps for the page from scratch. This can be quite expensive in terms of performance, especially if you're doing heavy calculations in your React code.
To mitigate this, you might want to consider expensive operations as much as possible.
In my case, I replaced the following code:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const router = useRouter();
const mypath = `/dashboard/some_path`;
router.push(mypath);
```

With:

```
const urlOrPath = `/dashboard/some_path`;
window.location.href= urlOrPath;
```

The href property of the Location interface is a stringifier that returns a string containing the whole URL, and allows the href to be updated.

Or:

```
const urlOrPath = `/dashboard/some_path`;
window.history.pushState({ someData: 'your data' }, 'unusedStr', urlOrPath);
```

The history.pushState() method adds an entry to the browser's session history stack.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And I managed to speed things up a bit by doing the following

- I had a fetch requests directly on the page so I guess the server has to do the fetching before rendering the UI so it takes time for the initial load.
- I moved this request to another server component and imported it in the page component
- I did this for any other places in other pages as well.
- I implemented react suspense. So in the initial load, page component has something to render.

This way I managed to reduce the page load time, which helped me to reduce the time between moving between pages.

So in summary my idea was to render what is available as soon as possible and render the components that are associated with API calls later. until they fetch the data, I showed a skeleton with the help of react suspense

Answer (score -4):

Hey I think you are in your production mode.
That's why it is slow. But if you will host your site it will be pretty much like react only.
But then also if you want to routing fast
Then npm i next@4.2.3 --save will work fine..

Answer (score -6):

to solve this issue followed the commands:

1. yarn build/nmp build
2. yarn start/npm start

I hope this will solve this issue