# How to deploy a NextJs SSR React app on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, next.js, azure-pipelines, server-side-rendering

I have been trying to deploy a Server-side rendered react app I built with NextJS on Azure. I set up the Azure pipeline and release successfully but after running it the app doesn't seem to load up when I went to the azure website URL. The build file content is different from a client rendered app. Please share a resource or explanation about deploying SSR React apps (on Azure).

I used [this resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMO-NQ1Xza0) to set up the pipeline and I encountered no error but the URL is still not loading the app.

Comment: You could have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ny5vJRfQito&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @James Does Doris's answer helps? If so, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT Yes, I'm all good now. The answer worked

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT This works but the app is very slow in production. takes like 6-10 mins to load and an average of 6 secs to move from one page to another. Please share a possible fix.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by @James in the comment in [Doris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974105/how-to-deploy-a-nextjs-ssr-react-app-on-azure/65986384#comment116797174_65986384), using a custom `server.js` in a Next.js app would make it slower in production because the routes aren't pre-built. [Using `next build` followed by `next start` would solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354574/6908282). But for you to be able to do that, you should not have a `server.js`.

And as per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#configure-nodejs-server) for deploying Node JS / Next JS application on Azure Linux web app, the recommended way is to use `PM2` rather than using [`npm start` (or) `node server.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779272/6908282).

So you [don't need `server.js` or `web.config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779272/6908282). All you need to do is to have a file called `ecosystem.config.js` with the below content

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my-nextJs-site",
      script: "./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      args: "start -p " + (process.env.PORT || 3000),
      watch: false,
      autorestart: true,
    },
  ],
};
```

and have the startup command for your Azure app to be this

```
pm2 --no-daemon start /home/site/wwwroot/ecosystem.config.js
```

and no change in your `package.json` scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
```

---

### Azure Windows App Service

`pm2` is not available in Azure Windows Service - [it uses IIS Server](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4822). Check out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098601/6908282) and its linked questions.

Other useful resources:

- [Deploying a Node.js application on Windows IIS using a reverse proxy](https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy)
- [Deploying Nextjs on IIS server without custom server](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13146#discussioncomment-1985004)
- [Deploying Nextjs on Digital Ocean - App Platform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ldjq5M7cbw)

Comment: its possible that your path is not correct. Check out the folder strucutre of your project in [Azure Kudu Environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service).  Additional info - [Kudu service overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu)

Answer (score 2):

You need two file: **server.js** and **web.config**, and modify **package.json** like below.  I've answered a question about deploy nextjs app step by step, you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758494/deploy-stripe-payment-gateway-on-azure/64783120#64783120).

**package.json modify.**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js"
```

**server.js** (create this file with the code below:)

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(req.url, 'http://w.w')
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

**web.config** (create this file with the code below:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works but the app is very slow in production. takes like 6-10 mins to load and an average of 6 secs to move from one page to another. Please share a possible fix.