# NextJS Azure WebApp Deployment Error: cannot find module ../server/require-hook

Tags: azure, next.js, github-actions

I'm having trouble deploying my nextjs application to my azure web app. The github-actions build and deployment complete successfully, however once deployed, I get an error in the url and this appears in the log stream. I don't understand what's causing it, as "npm start" builds and runs on my local machine with the same npm version. The application is in the "frontend" directory of my root file. Could that be an issue? Attached is the error and deployment files. Any help appreciated!

Build and Deployment Workflow:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - mm

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install --legacy-peer-deps
          npm run build --if-present
        working-directory: frontend

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'mm'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: frontend
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_******************************* }}
```

App Steam Error:

```
2024-01-26T14:19:35.427345342Z npm start
2024-01-26T14:19:43.527982622Z npm info using npm@9.6.4
2024-01-26T14:19:43.528330329Z npm info using node@v20.9.0
2024-01-26T14:19:43.728260894Z
2024-01-26T14:19:43.728298295Z > mm@0.1.0 start
2024-01-26T14:19:43.728303195Z > next start
2024-01-26T14:19:43.728306395Z
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180512023Z node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180579624Z   throw err;
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180584624Z   ^
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180601425Z
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180751728Z Error: Cannot find module '../server/require-hook'
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180757428Z Require stack:
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180760528Z - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180763728Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180766928Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180769928Z     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180773028Z     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180776029Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next:6:1)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180780029Z     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180783329Z     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180786429Z     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180789729Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180792729Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180796629Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180800029Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/next' ]
2024-01-26T14:19:44.180803029Z }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code in text format.If possible share your code repo.

Comment: In `yaml` file, change the package to `.` and check once.

Comment: Do you have `node_modules` folder in your GitHub..Looks like it is missing.

Comment: I do not have a node_modules in my GitHub, I assumed it was added during the “npm install” in the build process

Comment: Include the node_modules folder in thr GitHub repo and check once

Comment: The node modules exceed the size of a github repo limit

Comment: @JackHasselbring, Please provide your GitHub repository link..

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json**.
- Modify **Scripts** section  in **Package.json** as below:

```json
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "startAzure": "./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

- If you are using **pm2**, change the startup script as below:

```json
 module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "app-name",
      script: "./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      args: "start -p " + (process.env.PORT || 3000),
      watch: false,
      autorestart: true,
    },
  ],
};
```

- I have deployed a Nextjs application to Linux Azure App Service using GitHub actions.

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - <appname>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<appname>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_0A66FXXXXXXX6F0738 }}
          package: .
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**References:**

[node.js - How do I get my Next.js app to start in an Azure App Service running ubuntu-latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258454/how-do-i-get-my-next-js-app-to-start-in-an-azure-app-service-running-ubuntu-late)