# Next.js slow on page transition

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js

I am having problem with Next.js being too slow when going from `"/posts"` page to `"/post/[postId]"` and then go back to `"/posts"`.

As more posts gets loaded into cache going back to `"/posts"` Next.js waits until every posts gets rendered then goes back (I found out this by adding `console.log`) in one of the components and when I press back in `"/post/[postId]"` page I see the `console.log` running and when all of the 100 (for example) posts gets console logged then the page transitions which is very slow.

Compare this with Twitter's timeline and going back and forth for a specific tweet page it happens almost instantly, so in twitter the page immediately goes back and then tweets gets rendered (at least feels like this way).

I am fetching the posts on the client so the page is static with no `getServerSide` or `getStaticProps` or anything else.

Is it because twitter uses SPA React-Router? How to solve this issue in Next.js? I am sure other big sites have solved this issue but how?

Note that I am in production mode (not dev) and using `"/pages"` directory.

Maybe this is similar but not answering my question:
[NextJs router seems very slow compare to React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146878/nextjs-router-seems-very-slow-compare-to-react-router)

Answer (score -2):

I solved it via Delayed component and now router.back happens instantly but you will lose the SSR for SEO. (Google says that its bots will search dynamically generated content but who knows)

```js
function Delayed({
  timeout = 0,
  children,
}) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isShown) return

    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsShown(true)
    }, timeout)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    }
  }, [timeout])

  if (!isShown) return

  return children
}
```

and then

```js
<Delayed>
 <Content />
</Delayed>
```

If you have another way of solving this I will be glad to hear it.