# Deploy NextJS on Azure Devops App Service with Linux OS

Tags: azure-devops, next.js, azure-pipelines, pm2, azure-linux

I have the past three days really been struggling with getting my NextJS application deployed on Azure Devops. I have tried the PM2 solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908662/unable-to-deploy-next-js-to-azure) and the post posted by **Ravikumar B**.

Localy:
When i run the command `pm2 --no-daemon start ecosystem.config.js` my the application start whithout any problems.
[image]

After deploy to Azure Devops:

```
2021-12-20T23:48:47.221Z ERROR - Container my_app for site my_app__5494 did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.9727997 sec
2021-12-20T23:48:47.266Z ERROR - Container my_app__5494_0_817157c5 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2021-12-20T23:48:47.273Z INFO  - Stopping site my_app__5494 because it failed during startup.
```

I have also under App setting set the following:
EXPORT: 8080
PORT: 8080
WEBSITES_PORT: 8080

Does someone have any tips because right now nothing works...