# Cannot deploy Nextjs application on app service using Azure Pipleline

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js, azure-pipelines

I try to depoyed nextjs app to appservice using azure pipeline. First Build Stage and Deploy stage are worked. But when I go to `console` on app service, it don't create web.config and when I access the url it shows text like: "**You do not have permission to view this directory or page."**
My app work perfectly on Local.

Is there any steps I do wrong? Please help me,thank you.

Configuration:
appservice: OS-Windows, Node 16 /
Agents: OS Windows

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    - develop

pool: 'window-agent-fe'
stages:
  - stage: BuildStage
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: 'Instal Zip file Supported'
          inputs:
            script: 'sudo apt-get -y install zip'
        - task: NodeTool@0
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '16.x'
            checkLatest: true
          displayName: 'Install Node.js'
        - script: npm i --force
          displayName: 'Install Node Packages'
        - script: npm run lint
          displayName: Lint
        - script: npm run build
          displayName: 'Build'
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.next/'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: 'zip'
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            replaceExistingArchive: true
            verbose: true
        - publish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
          artifact: package
  - stage: 'DeployStage'
    dependsOn: BuildStage
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: 'DevDeployJob'
        environment: DEV
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - download: current
                  displayName: Download build file
                  artifact: package
                - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                  inputs:
                    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                    azureSubscription: '***********'
                    appType: 'webApp'
                    WebAppName: 'fpt-capstone-client'
                    packageForLinux: '$(System.WorkFolder)/1/package/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Error page from `Log stream`:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "**You do not have permission to view this directory or page."**

[image]

#### Follow workaround to fix the issue:

- The issue happens because of if we not added any of the **server.js** or **web.config** files.
- In your **package.json** file make sure to add the below line of code.

  ```json
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "next",
      "build": "next build",
      "start": "next start -p $PORT",
      "now-build": "next build"
  ```

  Instead of above you can use the below.

  ```json
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "node server.js",
      "build": "next build",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "now-build": "next build"
      }
  ```

  [image]
- While deploying your **nextjs** application into azure you have to add the **`web.config`** file in root directory. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942593/15997690)
  [image]
- In your **Server.js** file if you are using

  ```
  const  port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
  ```

  this try to change it like below

  ```
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  ```

  [image]
- If still you are facing the issue after deployed in a azure app service. Try to change your ***virtual Applications and Directories*** **`Physical Path`** like `\site\wwwroot\` into some your landing page like `\site\wwwroot\pages\index.html`
  [image]

#### Reference

- [Next js deployment on azure app service](https://parveensingh.com/next-js-deployment-on-azure-app-service/)